# Resetting Recall Depth in Angband

Tags: angband

In Angband, when you read a Scroll of Word Recall from a dungeon (say floor 40), reading it again from town returns you to *floor 40.*

Even if you go back from the first floor of the dungeon and read it again on, say, floor 10, reading it in town returns you to *floor 40*.

Is there any way to "reset" the recall depth to the current floor when in a dungeon instead of going back to the deepest level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took a look at the source code of Angband 3.1.0beta, and if I read it correctly, when you use a *Scroll of Word Recall* with a dungeon level smaller than the maximum visited dungeon level, you are asked whether or not you want to "*Reset recall depth?*". So, the new version of Angband should have the option to do it.

Some variants — Hengband at least — also have a *Scroll of Reset Recall* that does just that, reset your recall depth. I think it sets it to the current dungeon level (didn't check the source code for this one, just the [list of scrolls](http://www.kmc.gr.jp/~henkma/heng-e/magic_item2/index.html)).

Comment: You're right, it's when you recall from a different depth.